# create shortcuts in java with lib JShortcut

Tags: java, shortcut, lnk

I want to create shortcuts inwindows with code, I use the library here:
http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/jshortcut/README.html
also the corresponding codes:

```
import net.jimmc.jshortcut.JShellLink;
public class remove {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String path = new String ("/home/test.csv");
    readAndDelete(path, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

private static void readAndDelete(String path, boolean ignoreHeader,Charset encoding) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(file, encoding,CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader());
    List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();
    List<String> docRecord = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> shortpath = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (CSVRecord doctype : records){
         docRecord.add(doctype.get(0).toString());
         shortpath.add(doctype.get(1).toString());
    }
    int recordlength = docRecord.size();
    for(String eachdocRecord:docRecord){
        try {
            Path pathtemp=Paths.get(eachdocRecord);
            Files.delete(pathtemp);
        } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
            System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
        } catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
            System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
        } catch (IOException x) {
            // File permission problems are caught here.
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<recordlength; i++){
         JShellLink link = new JShellLink();
         String pointpath=shortpath.get(i);
         String originalpath = docRecord.get(i);
         String[] parts = pointpath.split("\\\\");
         int partssize= parts.length;
         String name=parts[partssize-1];
         String[] originalparts = originalpath.split("\\\\");
         int originalsize = originalparts.length;
         int lastlength = originalparts[originalsize-1].length();
         String foldername = originalpath.substring(0,originalpath.length()-lastlength);
         link.setFolder(foldername);
         link.setName(name);
         link.setPath(pointpath);
         link.save();
     }
 }
}
```

I run it in windows command prompt, but always exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:net/jimmc/jshortcut/JShellLink
```

I compiled the .class successfully ...
Anyone could save nme ... thanks a lot

Comment: is that the complete code? I don't see a method `public void main(String args[]) {}` which is required to run a java program from shell.

Comment: Did you add JShellLink to classpath?

Comment: @Deltharis.... no, if the filesystem like this: H:\src\TRUST in this folder, has jshortcut.jar, remove.class, remove.java. What should the classpath be? The code in JSHEllLink.class says set the path to the .dll file, but the .dll file is inside the jar.... thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of anything else that might be wrong (I did not read the entire code) the exception is quite clear - JShellLink is not on your classpath. How to do it best depends on your use case - README suggests editing Manifest file when you build to .jar, it should also be possible to use Maven to take care of that, and any IDE should have been able to take care of classpaths for you. As far as I can tell however your use case looks something like

```
javac remove.java
java remove
```

(By the way, class names and class file names should start with upper case, that's the standard)

In that case the simplest way to do that would be to use:

```
java -cp .;jshortcut.jar remove
```

We add current directory (due to JShortcut wanting to have it's dll on classpath, just to be sure) as well as the jar containing classes you use to the classpath. If you're on Unix system use `:` instead of `;`.